# How these two ids are same?

Tags: python

Wondering how x and y ids are same!

```
x='merchant_name'
y='merchant' + '_' + 'name'
print(id(x))
print(id(y))
```

output:

```
140291684960176
140291684960176
```

Comment: This happens due to internal optimization in CPython.